# How do I change the values of my dictionary from list type to string type

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, dictionary, type-conversion

I need to go from this output

```
3 ['and', 'may']
5 ['short']
6 ['coffee', 'monday', 'strong']
```

to this output

```
3 and may
5 short
6 coffee monday strong
```

this is my code so far:

```
dictionary = {6:['monday', 'coffee', 'strong'], 5:['short'], 3:['may', 'and']}

def print_keys_values_inorder(dictionary):
    for key in sorted(dictionary):
        print(key , sorted(dictionary[key]))

print_keys_values_inorder(dictionary)
```

how can I convert the values of my dictionary, which are in list type, to a string type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this following:

```
    dictionary = {6: ['monday', 'coffee', 'strong'], 5: ['short'], 3: ['may', 'and']}

    def print_keys_values_inorder(dictionary):
        for key in sorted(dictionary):
            print(key, ' '.join(map(str, sorted(dictionary[key]))))

    print_keys_values_inorder(dictionary)
```

OR if you want to avoid using map try this :

```
    dictionary = {6: ['monday', 'coffee', 'strong'], 5: ['short'], 3: ['may', 'and']}

    def print_keys_values_inorder(dictionary):
        for key in sorted(dictionary):
            print(key, *sorted(dictionary[key]))

    print_keys_values_inorder(dictionary)
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Out of curiosity and ignoring efficiency, is there a way to do this without using the join or map operator?

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain what the "*" did exactly in your code? Ive never seen it used like that before.

Comment: * symbol is use to print the list elements in a single line with space

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `print` buil-in function with [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
d = {3: ['may', 'and'], 5: ['short'], 6: ['monday', 'coffee', 'strong']}

print(*(' '.join(str(e) for e in (k, *v)) for k, v in d.items()), sep='\n')
```

output:

```
3 may and
5 short
6 monday coffee strong
```